# How to delete table in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to delete table from database using migration command in Laravel 5.8, Help me Out.

Comment: Schema::drop('table_name');

Comment: Laravel has [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#renaming-and-dropping-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete table like this way in laravel

```
Schema::drop('tableName');

//for more safe way
Schema::dropIfExists('tableName');
```

Comment: but how can i run this ?

Comment: After added this in to your migration file you will need to run php artisan migrate command